# How to join a table with another one and then with itself on SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables where `Table1` (t1) has the main data and `Table2` (t2) has the relations between data.

I need a query to get data from table (t1) where condition is like

```
WHERE t1.row = 1 AND t1.code = s1
```

But this query started with (`t1 left join t2 on t1.row = t2.row`) and then produced answer will join on t1 again on t2.trow = t1.row.

Then answer must have some columns and rows which is shown in bottom.

Can you help me with this query?

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

[image: Table Answer]

I wrote this query :

```
SELECT
    t1.code, t1_1.bed, t1_1.bes, 
    t2.t1row, t2.t2row
FROM 
    dbo.t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.t2 ON t1.row = t2.t1row
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.t1 t1_1 ON t2.t2row = t1_1.row
WHERE 
    t1.code = s1 And t1.row = '1'
```

But this query returns 2 rows where I need 5 rows!

Comment: Yes, we can **help** you - if you **SHOW US** what you have so far! We'll help - but we won't just write the whole code for you ....

Comment: Where does the `OK` come from? What is the condition for `OK` to appear in the result?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes When t1.row = 1 is present

Comment: @marc_s I will edit this question soon

Comment: Do you mean that you want to join on `t1.row = t2.frow` and when `t2.trow = 1` then output `OK`?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I wrote a query which will clarify the problem

Comment: You haven't explained the logic behind 'OK' for some rows

Comment: @JoakimDanielson When t2.trow = 1 then that is OK

Comment: What is the logic for the `'OK'`?  Your sample query doesn't return `'OK'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited question for more clarity. Please recheck that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to link back to `t1`, since simply joining `t1` with `t2` produces the desired result. If you `SELECT DISTINCT` then two similar rows are replaced by one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.row,
    CASE WHEN trow=1 THEN 'OK' ELSE null END AS t2_row,
    t1.bed, t1.bes, t1.code
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN t2
        ON t1.row = t2.frow
WHERE t1.code='s1'
ORDER BY t1.row;
```

Result:

```
row  t2_row   bed     bes  code
1            10000          s1
2     OK             7500   s1
3     OK             2500   s1
4            20000          s1
5                   20000   s1
```

Comment: Please recheck my question. I edited that for clarify . Thanks

Comment: The row names in your query do not match the ones in the image for `t2`. Also it, produces a result which is very different from your answer image. For instance it yields row=1, bed=null, bes=2500. But you want row=1, bed=10000, bes=null. So it doesn't clarify things. What is wrong with my answer? It produces exactly the required result.

Comment: (For instance it yields row=1, bed=null, bes=2500. But you want row=1, bed=10000, bes=null)  that's because it has 2 inner join ( t1 -> t2 -> t1 ) on different fields. Also, I can't find t1row (ON t1.row = t2.t1row) . Also I run this query in sql server but it didn't return 'OK'

Comment: I know it happens because of 2 inner join ( t1 -> t2 -> t1 ), but why do you want to join like this this if it produces the wrong result (i.e., not the result shown in table `answer`)? You don't find `t1row`, because in your example query you are using `t1row` and `t2row`, but in the `t2` picture you name them `frow` and `trow`. This is all very confusing.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of my answer apart from the order by

Comment: This is the true answer now. Thanks Olivier :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: This is not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE for t2.trow column and DISTINCT to remove duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT row,
    CASE WHEN trow = 1 THEN 'OK'
    ELSE ''
    END as t2_row,
    bed, bes, code
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.row = frow 
AND code = 's1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that this does what you want:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t2
                          where t2.frow = t1.row and
                                t2.frow <> 1
                         )
             then 'OK'
        end)
from t1
where t1.code = 's1';
```